# How to change the version in JitPack?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I published my library on GitHub and connected it with JitPack. The current version is 1.0. How can I change the version to 1.1? I changed the version in buiild.gradle, but it didn't help. What to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To make a new version create a [GitHub release](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software).

Source:
https://jitpack.io/docs/#publishing-on-jitpack

Answer (score 2):

From [jitpack docs](https://jitpack.io/docs/)

> -SNAPSHOT will build the latest commit on the master branch. It depends on your build tool how often it checks for new snapshot versions. or example, in Gradle add these lines to check for new versions on every build:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.cacheChangingModulesFor 0, 'seconds'
}
```

> Or you could also run Gradle from the command line with the `--refresh-dependencies` flag